# How to do a telnet from Solace appliance

Tags: solace

I want to telnet to check firewall opened from Solace to a server.
Telnet command is not available in Solace.
How do you do a telnet from Solace appliance?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on which VRF you want to check. There are two VRFs on the solace appliance: `management` and `msg-backbone`.

The `msg-backbone` VRF is mainly for the data plane where all messages get brokered. This is on specialized hardware, and there is no support for the regular Linux networking stack. Telnet naturally is not supported. You can, however, test ping connectivity through the CLI: `ping msg-backbone:<ip-address>`.

The `management` VRF, as the name suggests is for management traffic. This is on a typical ethernet NIC and is on the Linux networking stack. SolOS base is a CentOS-7 image. So the answer can be found in https://serverfault.com/questions/788934/check-if-remote-host-port-is-open-cant-use-gnu-netcat-nor-nmap-rhel-7.